# Buttons placement inside CardView

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-cardview

I try to make a View with two card views.
In one of them I would like to place two buttons: bottom right ("btn_save") and bottom left ("btn_cancel") but I can't place the bottom right ("btn_save") button.
I've tried to align the button with app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" but no success.
How can I place these buttons in the correct way?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView

        android:id="@+id/text_card"
        android:layout_width="0sp"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:backgroundTint="#eceaf3"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.7"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.8"
        app:rippleColor="#00c89e"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <--
        Some design elements are here...  
        -->

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/menu_card"
        android:layout_width="0sp"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:backgroundTint="#eceaf3"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.7"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.8"
        app:rippleColor="#00c89e">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginStart="15sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
            android:text="Cancel" />

           <--
           I have a problem with this button:  
           -->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_save"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
            android:text="Save"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: add a ConstraintLayout inside cardView

Comment: i can almost guarantee as soon as you add `tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"`  to any of your layouts, it isn't going to work when you run your app, ignoring the error doesn't make it go away...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MaterialCardView` `extends` `FrameLayout`, which don't have methods for lying child `View`s next to each. just put straight inside `MaterialCardView` some `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` and inside of this addtional `ViewGroup` place your `Button`s

PS. please don't use `sp` unit in that way, you should use [`dp`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/what-is-the-difference-between-px-dip-dp-and-sp). `sp` is for fonts only

Answer (score 1):

Use a `ViewGroup` as child of your `CardView`; like a `ConstraintLayout` or a `LinearLayout`, you can easily place your button inside those `ViewGroup` and manage the alignment.